# Help - Ubuntu creates a temp file for every file I edit

Tags: nautilus, files, gedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent gedit from creating files with the '~' suffix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-suffix)

I dont know how to explain it very well so I took a picture of it.

It seems that every time I edit a Text file and save it, the sistem makes a file with the changes or whatever next to the other file. I am making a website and when I copy them through ftp it takes longer becaouse of those files, and i have to delete them one by one in the folder every time I edit them

[image]

Comment: Here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-suffix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use **gedit**?

If so, uncheck the following settings in *Edit | Preferences* menu:

File Saving:

- Create a backup copy of files before saving
- Autosave files in every [ ] minutes

Doing so will disable these *„safety features”* of the editor. It might be better though to keep these enabled and *run a pre-upload script* to clean up the unwanted files (or filter them in your synchronization client).

Comment: Thankyou! It helped me a lot. Its good to know that I can do that, although I used the script solution.

Comment: The Script:

#! /bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*.*~" -exec rm -i '{}' \;

Save it and give it execute permission, then run