# Dropbox syncing file.ext~ (tilde, backup/temp)

Tags: windows, sync, dropbox

When using Dropbox in Ubuntu everything seems fine, but on my Windows machine with Dropbox I end up with the file.ext~ backup/temp version of any files I opened in Ubuntu. Is there some way to prevent this? I found several forum topics about this matter on the Dropbox forum but they are all expired and unviewable. (Side note: why would you hide your forum's aggregated knowledge?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No current way to do it. Your best bet is to disable autosaving of the gedit files (I'm assuming thats the app you are using):

[Prevent gedit from creating files with the '~' (tilde) suffix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-suffix)

Also, vote up this feature request with Dropbox for the option:

https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/2385/option-to-exclude-by-file-extension

EDIT: the above link is broken as Votebox is discontinued. 
You may want to go here instead: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=59743

If they ever implement that, it should work for your uses (file ext would just be ~)