# Why does Ubuntu create a file ending in ~ for every file I create with a text editor like GNU Emacs?

Tags: filesystem, files, emacs

> Why does Ubuntu create a file ending in ~ for every file I create with a text editor ?

Creating a file with a text editor like GNU Emacs, say myfile, another file called myfile~ is also created. Why is this superfluous file created ? Using `cat` on it displays nothing.

Thanks,

Comment: Linking to that post since http://askubuntu.com/questions/154474/what-are-the-files-created-when-i-edit-something-and-can-i-delete-them?lq=1 was closed as an exact dup.

Comment: Note: this is **nothing** to do with the OS, only with the application. For example `kate` by default does this too, and you can install it on Windows too. You can simply go to its settings and tell him to avoid creating backups.

Comment: `vim` does it too by default

Comment: Ubuntu's default editor `gedit` also does this, and you can turn it off in its settings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Emacs' default mode is to create a backup file with a "~" suffix every time you edit and save a file. You can disable this by creating a `.emacs` file in your home directory and [setting an option inside it](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/acs/rpinfo/common/Computing/Consulting/Software/Emacs/Hints/backup.html). This happens with Emacs on all platforms. Other editors may do the same under Ubuntu, but it has nothing to do with Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 6):

It's a backup file that contains the file's content from before saving and will be created every time you save the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see now that this is the case for my files. Does this apply to every file in Ubuntu, or is it specific to GNU Emacs ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I think it's an emacs thing. For example if I open a file in nano and make edits, I don't get the `~` file

Comment: Some other programs do that, too. Files with names ending in `~` are usually backup files. Some programs, like Nautilus, have an option to hide backup files, which means they don't display those files.

Answer (score 6):

It's `emacs`(and `xemacs`and `jed`) -- not Ubuntu -- that creates those files.  It's a copy of the previous version of the file your editing, ie. the file as it was before you made changes and used "save" to save them.  I admit it's often a bother, but it's certainly useful if you've make changes you later regret.

It can be turned off manually -- and you can turn it off by default in the `.emacsrc` file.

Personally I run a cron-job that removes back-ups that hasn't been accessed for more than a week.

`emacs` also make files called something "#filename#" and ".#filename#".  This file contained unsaved changes -- ie. things you've done since last save.  The file is periodically updated as you edit a file.  If `emacs` (or your computer) crashes, you'll be asked to continue with the "recovered buffer" if you try to edit the file again.  (These files I also periodically "cron-away".)

My advice, keep letting `emacs` make back-ups... sooner or later you'll regret it if you don't.