# Duplicate file ~ in root folder

Tags: files, hidden-files

I have a copy of all the files in my root folder with ~ symbol. I can see it on the terminal but not in the folder. How do i stop this

Comment: So what is the output of the location, and where exactly is it?

Comment: Note that you view the files (in Nautilus atleast) by pressing 'Ctrl'+'H' in File manager.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case:

To prevent Gedit from creating backups in the future, open up gedit, open up the Preferences dialog (Edit > Preferences), select the Editor tab, remove the check in the “Create a backup copy of files before saving” option, and click Close. After doing this, Gedit will no longer make the backups with tildes all over the place.

Please, include more details to receive more feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. These are backup files generated by most editors when you change a text file. You really shouldn't worry about them, and they can very often save you. They are not shown in the GUI because they are considered hidden files.

While you can disable their creation by tweaking the settings of the editor you use (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix) for how to do this for `gedit`), I strongly recommend that you leave them be. You never know when having them might save you from loosing a few hours of work.