# What does the ~ symbol mean next to the files that are listed with ls?

Tags: command-line, ls

I created a file named `xxx` on my Desktop and then I (re)moved it using terminal. Now when I execute `ls` on Desktop I see a file named `xxx~` that is not visible at GUI. What does it mean?

Comment: You will find your answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix; this question is a duplicate of that one (or at least you will find your answer there).

Comment: Backup automatically created from a program, more commonly text editors

Comment: @OrganicMarble is right. I just couldn't see the fact that how all those files are derived from other files that I used with gedit. The question he/she marked mine as a duplicate of has all the answers and more I'd need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that is a backup file