# Would it be possible to save gedit backup files in a "specific" Folder?

Tags: backup, gedit

Based on this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix) I 
would like to know if it would be possible (and if so how) to save these auto-saved backup files into a specific or different folder.

As I'm using git as a revision control system and don't want always once I join a project to change the `.gitignore` file as this might be disliked to some extent.

Comment: @Rinzwind that is the obvious solution. But i was wondering if there could be something else as all my other colleagues either use an other editor (vim/Emacs, i don't really feel comfortable with them) or develop on windows!

Comment: @Medi1Saif don't commit changes to `.gitignore`. Stash and pop as needed.

Comment: @muru sounds as an interesting hint, i never used stash/pop before but must check to what extent this is allowed, as we have some presetting for our repos!

Comment: @Rinzwind sounds good, but will need some work and time. But i will put it on my To Do list to try it!

Comment: @Rinzwind a git `pre-commit` hook? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: If you change to Geany, you can set any folder you like to store back-ups. What's more, you can set a date/time format like this: `/home/dkb/Public/Backups/.gtkrc-2.0.2016-02-06-18-47-34`.

Comment: You'll have to enable the "Save Actions" plugin under `Tools, Plugin Manager`. This is a built-in plug-in.

Comment: @DKBose it works fine... that was really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this with gedit. This was a [declined feature request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108868). It can apparently be done with a plugin, but such a plugin is not published - not that I can find, anyway,

Comment: Well i should have investigated in two different directions of course git has a solution with a local ignore -> .git/info/exclude which is a good workaround also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally!