# Dropbox litters my folders with unhidden backup files

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

**Edit:** I have mistaken dropbox for `gedit`'s default backup feature, see below.

As the title says when I create a file in any dropbox synchronized folder it creates an unhidden (no `.` prefix) duplicate backup file with a `~` after the original name.

For example, if I create a file `file1`, dropbox creates a backup `file1~`.

This drives me crazy in editors with tree navigation menus and litters the folders in general. I would be very thankful if someone could suggest a possible solution to this (either how to hide the backup files or get rid of them altogether).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Dropbox for years and never seen this behavior. On the other hand, this *is* typical behavior for some text editors. If you are creating files with your editor, check its Settings for a switch to turn this behavior off.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveEmme, for your prompt response and pointing me to the right direction. You were right about the editor; it is the default behavior of gedit if the backup option is checked. Here is a [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix) discussing exactly that.