# I have a problem with what I think is a broken link

Tags: files

HEre image attached of one example. index.html and index.html~ appears everytime I finish editing the file. But it does not have any content and it does not go away unless I delete it, but, I am afraid of deleting the actual file. [image: index-html~]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent gedit from creating files with the '~' (tilde) suffix](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix)

Answer (score 0):

The `index.html~` is meant to be a backup of the file.

When you edit a file with Gedit, Ubuntu saves the original as `filename~`. The backup file is supposed to reflect what the original file looked like before it was edited.

It doesn't contain a whole backup history. It just keeps the last version of the file for you.