# 'ls' shows more files in directory than nautilus

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, directory, ls

In home directory `ls` shows the following:

[image: terminal with ls]

But let's look what is in Nautilus.

[image: nautilus with home folder]

I refreshed Nautilus many times. `rm 1.1.c` returns a error `there is no such file in directory`.

What's wrong?

Comment: Files ending with '~' are backup files (mostly from text editors). Nautilus doesn't seem to show them (maybe shows them if you modify some option(s)). To remove the files, you have to give the '~' as well; so `rm 2.1.cpp~`. There is no `1.1.c`in your listing - maybe a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent gedit from creating files with the '~' (tilde) suffix](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus has an option you can toggle by clicking on **View** to toggle **Show Hidden Files** files to on or off.

If you click the **Show Hidden Files** option you will see the hidden bakup files in Nautilus.

Files that end with the tilde (`~`) or begin with the dot (`.`) are hidden files.

Examples of hidden files:

```
2.1.cpp~
2.2.cpp~
.bashrc
.history
```

Your `ls` command would show even more files if you used the `-a` argument.

Type in this:

```
$ ls -a
```

You will then see substantially more files.